# Source Destination Edit Box in Google MAP API V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I have added Google Map API v2 in my android app.

```
<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Now I need to add source and destination Edit box.I have searched google developer Website, But didn't find any help regarding this.Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJguXeAk9OU) step by step, you will finally get destination in your map app.

[Here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMapExample-android) is the whole source code on my github, please check it if you want.